# Chapter and pages of a bibliography item are not displayed

Tags: bibliographies

I have a problem with correct bibliography display. I created a simple bibliography which looks like

```
@BOOK
{
    CONTENTBASEDIMAGERETRIEVAL,
    AUTHOR = { J.Eakins and M.Graham},
    TITLE = {Content-based Image Retrieval},
   PUBLISHER = {University of Northumbia at Newcastle},
   CHAPTER = {What is CBIR ?},
    PAGES = {9--10 },
    YEAR  = {1999}
}
```

I refer to this book in text by using `\cite{CONTENTBASEDIMAGERETRIEVAL}`. However in the last page of document I can see only basic information about the book, but I can't see chapter and pages. What do I do wrong?
Of course I compiled bibliography as well as my document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the @inbook template. the following snippet produces what you want.

```
@inbook {ref,
    author = {J.Eakins and M.Graham},
    title = { What is CBIR? },
    booktitle = { Content-based Image Retrieval },
    publisher = { University of Northumbia at Newcastle },
    year = { 1999 },
    pages = { 9--10 }
}
```

update: if you want the title to be displayed you should use '@incollection' instead.